# Combining validation and json to store value

Tags: javascript

This is my html register page for entering the details:

```
<form id = "tform" onsubmit="return false;">
<h1>Register</h1>  
   <p><label>Name</label>
   <br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
   </p>
   <p><label>Username</label>
   <br><input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
   </p>
   <p><label>Create Password</label>
   <br><input type="password" id="psw" name="psw">
   </p>                        
   <p><label>Confirm Password</label>
   <br><input type="password" id = "pswc" name=psw>
   </p><input type ="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validform()">                    
   </form>
```

The validation code works but I would also like to implement json function so I can store the user data when I enter all the details correctly, it works separately but I don't know how to combine the two. Here is my code for json:

```
function StoreUser(){
    var userObj = {};
    userObj.name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    userObj.username = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    userObj.password = document.getElementById("psw").value;

    //Store user
    localStorage[userObj.name] = JSON.stringify(userObj);

    //Inform user of result
    document.getElementById("tform").innerHTML = "<b> Register Done";
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My validation function works for register and so does storeUser for storing the local values but how do I use both of them in my register, basically call two function with one button.

Comment: Create another function that calls them one after the other?

Comment: Yes I have two functions, one button..